# Google Colab not achieve the model training

Tags: google-colaboratory

I try several times to train the following model on Google Colab but it's disconnect permanently (on the 5 or 6 epoch) and the training will never be done. I try also the JavaScript function that maintain the session when the button connect was clicked but not work.How I can resolve this problem please ?

```
classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(6, (3, 3), input_shape = (30, 30, 3), data_format="channels_last", activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(6, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

opt = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-08, decay = 0.0)
classifier.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy', precision, recall, fmeasure])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   vertical_flip = True,
                                   rotation_range = 180)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (30, 30),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

validation_set = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/dataset/validation_set',
                                                        target_size = (30, 30),
                                                        batch_size = 32,
                                                        class_mode = 'binary')

history = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                                   steps_per_epoch = 208170,
                                   epochs = 25,
                                   validation_data = validation_set,
                                   validation_steps = 89140)
```

Answer (score 0):

Colab will automatically close your notebook after 8-9 hours so you should checkpoint the model after each epoch into google drive

Comment: But in this way the model was trained on 5 epochs for example, but this is not what I would (25 epoch)

Comment: Save and then continue training until you reach 25 epoch

Comment: I can continue from the 5th epoch ?

Comment: Yes. Look up save and load models

Comment: Please can you tell me how I can add the code that can figure this on my own

Comment: you can see sample code here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load